# What needs to be done to cleanly move a MediaWiki installation from one server to another?

Tags: migration, mediawiki

I have MediaWiki running on one server, and need to migrate it to another. What steps need to be taken to cleanly move it to another host? Minimal downtime is acceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried checking [MediaWiki's process for moving a Wiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Moving_a_wiki)?

The short version is:

```
Back up the database
Back up the MediaWiki files
Re-create the database, user and permissions
Import the database backup
Import the MediaWiki files
Check the configuration file
Test
```